# how to get the label value using button action in iOS

Tags: iphone, uicollectionviewcell, ios6.1

i want to get the label value by using perform button action using uicollectionviewcell in iOS. i have four label add as subview to uibutton in uicollectionviewcell. how to get the selected index uilabel  value using button action.

Comment: `[UICollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]`?  Looks pretty trivial to me.

Comment: please give me the sample code i am new to iPhone...

Comment: No.  You attempt a solution and post back if you can't get it working.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: get the selected index uilabel value by using ibaction method using uicollectionview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom collection view cell class subclassed from UICollectionViewCell.In that class you can create labels and buttons from the storyboard.

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface AudioListViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl1;

   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl2;

   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl3;

   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

   @end
```

Change the Class name of collectionview cell in story board as custom cell class name.Here AudioListViewCell.

In your viewcontroller in the collection view delegate method "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" you can get the labels text vlaue.This is one approach.
If you want to get the label text in button click, you have to add selector for the button in collectionvew cell and each buttons tag value is same as collection view index. Then You can get each label inside a button using the followng code.

```
     for (UILabel * lbl in button.subviews) {

        if(lbl1.tag == uniqueLabelTag1)strVal1=  lbl1.text;

        else if(lbl2.tag == uniqueLabelTag2)strVal2= lbl2.text;

        else if (lbl3.tag == uniqueLabelTag3) strVal3 = lbl3.text;

     }
```

You can create label tag from button tag ie. for example if your button tag of first collection view cell is 1 then your lbl1 tag can 1100, lbl2 tag can 1200 and lbl3 tag can 1300.If second button tag will be 2 then lbl1 tag can 2100, lbl2 can 2200 and lbl3 tag can 2300 and so on.